# Python / Selenium-webdrivers doesn't work on cloudlinux x86 64bit / cpanel

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, cpanel

My solution works locally on windows 10. with python 3.12

Deployed to a linux server with Python 3.11.5, I get the exception:

```
Service /home/project/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/repositories/fam/fam.py", line 23, in init_browser
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/project/virtualenv/repositories/fam/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/project/virtualenv/repositories/fam/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/project/virtualenv/repositories/fam/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/project/virtualenv/repositories/fam/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/project/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
```

#### Python code:

```
def init_browser():
    #Init browser
    logging.info("Initializing browser object")
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless=new') 
        # block image loading
        options.experimental_options['prefs'] = {
        "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2
        }
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception(ex)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return browser
```

#### Relevant log output

```
shell
Selenium Manager binary found at: /home/project/virtualenv/repositories/fam/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager
Executing process: /home/project/virtualenv/repositories/fam/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --debug --output json
chromedriver not found in PATH
chrome not found in PATH
chrome not found in the system
Discovering versions from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json
Required browser: chrome 119.0.6045.105
chrome 119.0.6045.105 already exists
chrome 119.0.6045.105 is available at /home/project/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chrome
Discovering versions from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json
Required driver: chromedriver 119.0.6045.105
chromedriver 119.0.6045.105 already in the cache
Driver path: /home/project/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver
Browser path: /home/project/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chrome
Using driver at: /home/qproject/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver
Started executable: `/home/project/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver` in a child process with pid: 365909
```

I've submitted a bug at github SeleniumHQ. They gave up. Hope you guys can help!
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13223

#### What have I tried?

I've tried altering the code to:

- use local binarys for webdriver and browser executable
- Both chrome and Firefox
- use custom port numbers like 8080 and 80 with

```
--remote-debugging-port=8080
```

### added arguments:

```
-disable-dev-shm-usage
```

```
--no-sandbox
```

**and ANY combination of the above**

Linux filepermissions checked. You can see them at the github link.

The only new error I have is when I'm using Chrome with binarys I downloaded myself:

```
2023-12-01 13:19:23 - INFO - root - Initializing browser object
2023-12-01 13:19:23 - INFO - root - Browser type is chrome
2023-12-01 13:19:23 - INFO - root - Local files are used
2023-12-01 13:19:23 - DEBUG - selenium.webdriver.common.service - Started executable: `/home/project/home/selenium_drivers/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver` in a child process with pid: 1431566
2023-12-01 13:19:24 - ERROR - root - Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/project/home/selenium_bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: this is to do with the different between the operating systems. the same exact code won't work in both...

Comment: Please specify in detail what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A2 shared hosting does not support "anything that runs chrome or firefox"**

So, after many hours of grief. I decided to contact my hosting support. After they spent 1 hour of chatting with me and trying different solutions, they turned around and said:

```
[16:35:21]  [name]: Unfortunately, we don't support puppet on shared hosting.
[16:35:35]  [name]: puppet/selenium/anything that runs chrome or firefox is not supported in shared hosting.
```

This is not in their terms og knowledge base.
You heard it here first.

**A2 shared hosting does not support "anything that runs chrome or firefox"**